# Getting the ID of an li using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<li id ="+ "'" + response.set[i].LessonID + "'" +">" + response.set[i].no_of_questions[x].informed + "</li>"
```

The above code is supposed to set the ID of a list item to a variable in json array. My issue is I want to be able to pick the ID from the list generated and store it in local variable. Can anyone help ? I want something specific to this situation.
This is the Code I was using :

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var listId = (this).attr('id');
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Comment: You have a typo, you're missing the `$` where you get the id: `var listId =  $(this).attr('id');`. Also check that the HTML is being generated properly. You have some odd syntax around the quotes.

Comment: @freedomn-m I meant more the redundant appending of string literals, ie. `"this" + "that"`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo :) missed the $

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function() {
        var listId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    })

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='test'></div>

    <ul style="list-style-type:square">
      <li id='id_1'>Coffee</li>
      <li id='id_2'>Tea</li>
      <li id='id_3'>Milk</li>
    </ul>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put "$" before "(this).attr('id');"

change

```
(this).attr('id');
```

to

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem looks like you're missing `$` before the `(this).attr('id');`

You have

`var listId = (this).attr('id');`

which should be changed to

`var listId = $(this).attr('id');`

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    var listId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(listId);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="li1">List Item 1</li>
  <li id="li2">List Item 2</li>
  <li id="li2">List Item 3</li>
<ul>
```

Here another way of doing on click (This is what I usually use to do my on click)

```js
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    var listId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(listId);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="li1">List Item 1</li>
  <li id="li2">List Item 2</li>
  <li id="li2">List Item 3</li>
<ul>
```